# Anylogic 7 - Conveyor Space

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to limit the capacity of a conveyor in anylogic 7. On the anylogic page it says the capacity is determined by its length divided by the space parameter.

Unfortunately I'm unable to find the space option within the conveyors preferences window.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem or know where the option is hidden?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

there is an "Agent length" parameter in the conveyor properties. However, you need to activate it by ticking "change agent length". If your speed is 0.02 m/s and the agent length is 1m, you can take in a new agent every 50 seconds.

Hope this helps.
Ben